# Using Gson to deserialize a RSAPublicKey

Tags: java, serialization, encryption, gson

I am trying to deserialize a `RSAPublicKey` with Gson but it is not working as I'd wish. Gson first complained because it said `RSAPublicKey` did not have a no-arg constructor, so I created an `InstanceCreator` as:

```
public static class PublicKeyInstanceCreator implements InstanceCreator<RSAPublicKey> {
    public RSAPublicKey createInstance(final Type type) {
        try {
            final KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyGen.initialize(2048);
            final KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
            return (RSAPublicKey) key.getPublic();
        } catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and registered it when creating the Gson object

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(RSAPublicKey.class, new PublicKeyInstanceCreator()).create();
```

Now Gson seems to run fine, however the `RSAPublicKey` object which is created from parsing the Json file is whatever `RSAPublicKey` object is returned from the `PublicKeyInstanceCreator` i.e the fields are never changed during the deserialization process. How can I get Gson to correctly return the object I want?

Comment: What exactly is it that you want? Gson generally serializes the fields of a class. If you want something else, you need to write and register a `TypeAdapter`.

Comment: To deserialize a `RSAPublicKey` object with Gson which was previously serialized using Gson. Do I need to write a `TypeAdapter` for serialization? How would I do that when I don't know the implementation of `RSAPublicKey`?

Comment: It's much easier to serialize a byte array and back. If you call `.getEncoded()` and then use the `"X509"` `KeyFactory` and `X509EncodedKeySpec` to turn it back. This would use the standard encoding for a public key (SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure from X.509).